# Best & least-well adapted flora & fauna in a high-Oxygen atmosphere

Tags: earth-like, fauna, flora, xenobiology

Positing a high (c. 35%) O₂-level on a roughly Earth-equivalent planet (atmosphere about like the early Carboniferous), what types of lifeforms would flourish?

Obviously, giant insects could be possible, but there's no need to assume Earth-like evolution.

And what about fish? Would something like Rhizodontia be possible/probable? They're from an earlier epoch here on Earth, but could they not have survived? Any advantage/disadvantage to different marine species given the high atmospheric O₂?

Also, I'm particularly interested in the development of two other organisms: fungi and aspens. Any thoughts about their respective susceptibilities to high-O₂ environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well aspens appear to be adapted to forest fires, so can already be considered a [fire ecology](http://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/beauty/aspen/ecology.shtml) plant. Fires will be more frequent in a 35% oxygen atmosphere, so any and all plants adapted to survive periodic fire will do well (in comparison to those which are damaged or killed).

Meanwhile, IIRC fungi require lots of oxygen to break down lignin (the stuff that makes wood in trees hard and durable). So fungi may be decomposing fallen trees and infecting living trees faster than now.

Marine life... the depth of the [oxygen minimum zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_minimum_zone) will be deeper. However, how that affects all marine life depends on some other features of your planet. Ice caps are the pumping mechanism to get oxygenated water to the bottom of the deepest oceans, so currently the oxygen minimum zone is at a midwater depth. If you've got no ice caps, then oxygen just gets less and less with depth, and the minimum will be zero oxygen (in very deep water).

Answer (score 3):

Evolution of aerobic creatures would favor gigantic creatures. This is especially true for ancient types of body forms (i.e. amphibians and reptiles). If insects are present, they would also tend to acquire gigantic sizes.

Most land based creatures would *probably* be adapted for cold temperatures as large oxygen concentrations in the atmosphere tend to react with methane (a powerful greenhouse gas) and remove it, hence dropping temperatures on global scale.

Quadrupeds will tend to be faster and more agile than their counterparts under normal oxygen concentrations. Creatures with air-sac respiration systems will attain unbelievable speed and agility. Personally I think air-sac respiration method would quickly vanish, due to ready availability of oxygen without the complex air-sac system.

Methanogens will be hard hit, as oxygen is lethal for them.

Fish will also attain larger sizes, but that would be largely due to colder temperatures (larger animals are better insulated than smaller ones) than more readily supply of oxygen.

Coastal areas would have many times greater biodiversity than they have now.

Comment: I chose DrBob's answer as best, but there's great--and different--info in your answer, too. Particularly interested in the impact on methanogens.

Answer (score 1):

Fish would not be affected because the water holds as much oxygen as it can, and is already far less than the concentration in air.

You mentioned insects, as indeed they don't have lungs and their size is limited by their ability to get air to the cells.  So most animals would not care or notice the higher level of oxygen.

It would enable *high altitude* life to go higher, as more oxygen is still available.